# Adding a folder creates a submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-tower

When I add some particular folders then git tower creates a submodule for that folders. I don't want to create a submodule.

Some pattern I notice is that inside this `XYZ` folder there is a folder named `MyFolder` and there is one more folder with same name `MyFolder` which is in same directory as the folder which is made submodule.

I don't know if its the issue. And yes then how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by first removing the folder `MyFolder` which is converted to submodule by git tower (I committed `XYZ` though).

```
git rm --cached path/to/submodule
rm -rf path/to/submodule
```

Then adding `MyFolder` to `XYZ` again and committing solved the problem.

```
cd path/to/XYZ
git add MyFolder/
git commit -m "Added MyFolder" MyFolder/
```